# Diagonalisation and direct sums

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ be a finite dimensional vector space. Let $T:U\to U$ be a linear transformation with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$. Then $T$ is diagonalisable if and only if $$U=E_{\lambda_1}\oplus...\oplus\, E_{\lambda_n}.$$ Where $\oplus$ denotes the direct sum and $E_{\lambda_i}$ is the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$.

---

My lecturer states this proof is immediate given that eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent. Could anyone explain this or give a fuller proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: show that both are equivalent to "$U$ has a basis consisting solely of eigenvectors for $T$".